# VS2015 Debugger is not starting after deploy on android device

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have the problem that my Debugger will not start after deploying the cordova app on the android device. The app will be deployed and starts on the device but Visual Studio (VS 2015 CTP 5) could not attach the debugger respectively the process line shows the the build already runs.

The device using android 4.4.2 and the dependencies for Cordova with Visual Studio are all up to date.

In the past with the last Visual Studio 2015 Preview it works, after updating to CTP 5 it is not working.

Does anybody have an idea what I could do to solve this issue?

Many Thanks for your help!